# Passenger door central locking only half works

Tags: car, central-locking

In my car, when I lock or unlock the driver-side door by pushing the button, the passenger door only partially locks/unlocks most of the time, so I have to reach over and lock/unlock it.

Sometimes it works, but usually it only half locks/unlocks.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

One of three things are the probable cause of this. The first most likely cause is bent, loose, worn linkage or obstructions in the locking mechanism. The door panel must be removed and the linkage inspected for any of these conditions. The second most likely problem would be a worn lock actuator motor. The door panel will have to be removed to replace it. The third most likely cause would be a fault in the wiring that would limit the current provided to the lock actuator. Again the door panel must be removed to test.